# Get a number from a name

Tags: javascript, parsing, google-apps-script

So I have objects listed like favoriteImage1, favoriteImage2... favoriteImage22. How do I get the number at the end of word? I tried parseInt but it returns undefined. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Can you show the serialized string ?

Comment: FYI, `parseInt` will actually return `NaN`.  It *can* parse out numbers at the beginning of the string, but not at the end.  A regular expression is probably your best bet here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
var string  = "favoriteImage1";
var num = +string.replace(/\D/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the name will always have the prefix "favoriteImage", you could also do

```
var x  = "favoriteImage1";
var num = parseInt(x.substring(13));
```